# Selma - Bad custom field to field mapping

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have a project that uses Mapstrcut, i want to replace it by Selma, so in the below example i mapped AttachmentRequest to Attachment

```
public class Attachment {
    private SocialReason socialReason;
    public SocialReason getSocialReason() { return socialReason; }
    public Attachment socialReason(SocialReason socialReason) { this.socialReason = socialReason; return this; }
}

public class SocialReason {
    private String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public SocialReason value(String value) { this.value = value; return this; }
}

public class AttachmentRequest {
    private String socialReason;
    public String getSocialReason() { return socialReason; }
    public AttachmentRequest socialReason(String socialReason) { this.socialReason = socialReason; return this; }
}
```

I tried with the bellow code, but i have this error

> Bad custom field to field mapping: field out.getSocialReason().value
> from destination bean Attachment has no setter !
> -->  Fix @Field({"socialreason","socialreason.value"})

```
@Mapper(withIgnoreMissing = IgnoreMissing.ALL)
public interface AttachmentCommandMapper {
    @Maps(withCustomFields = { @Field({ "socialReason", "socialReason.value" }) })
    Attachment attachmentRequestToAttachment(AttachmentRequest attachmentRequest);
}
```

Is setters required in the class for the mapping in Selma, because in mapstruct doesn't require setters.

Comment: Is there something missing in MapStruct that makes you want to switch to another mapping framework?